# @JsonInclude not all properties from the object

Tags: java, spring, spring-restcontroller

I have this attribute inside a class:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "id_object", nullable = true)
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public Object someObject;
```

This object can be null, but when it is not, I want to bring only one field of the someObject, not all its fields.

I can not use JsonIgnore inside Object because in other endpoints I want to bring all the fields of that object.

Is there any parameter I can pass inside @JsonInclude to return in json only one or two Object fields?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps using mixins would be a suitable approach to this.

This will allow you to return different parameters of the same object under different conditions

Comment: do you have a example with mixins?

Comment: This should give you enough information https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs/wiki/JacksonMixInAnnotations . Use different mixins for your two use cases

Comment: Thanks for the answer doddi76, i solved using HATEOAS: https://spring.io/understanding/HATEOAS